# Pairwise Dijkstra's with early termination according to hop-count in R

Tags: r

I am looking for the most computational and memory friendly approach to computing particular entries of the distance matrix D obtained by pairwise Dijkstra's algorithm in R. More precisely, I only need D[i,j] if the hop-count (unweighted) distance between node i and node j is at most a particular integer k (D[i,j] itself may computed as a weighted shortest path length for which the number of hops may be greater than k). D should be encoded as a sparse matrix for memory efficiency.

I was wondering if there has been some work done on this or if there is an efficient approach towards optimizing the current igraph functions to account for this restriction. E.g., early exit in pairwise Dijkstra's algorithm could really improve the efficiency of solving my problem.

I have tried to make this as efficient as possible myself, but with no luck so far. Some first attempt is illustrated below.

```r
library(igraph)
library(Matrix)
library(spam)

# Hope this to the more efficient one
bounded_hop_pairG_1 <- function(G, k=2){
  to <- ego(G, order=k)
  D <- sparseMatrix(i=unlist(lapply(1:length(V(G)), function(v) rep(v, length(to[[v]])))),
                    j=unlist(to),
                    x=unlist(lapply(1:length(V(G)), function(v) distances(G, v=v, to=to[[v]]))))
  return(D)
}

# Hope this to be the less efficient one
bounded_hop_pairG_2 <- function(G, k=2){
  D <- distances(G)
  D[distances(G, weight=NA) > k] <- 0
  return(as.spam(D))
}

# Sample graph
set.seed(42)
G <- sample_bipartite(500, 500, p=0.1)
E(G)$weight <- runif(length(E(G)))

# Check whether 'distances' actually implements early termination
start_time <- Sys.time()
d1 <- distances(G, v=1)
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
# Time difference of 0.00497961 secs

start_time <- Sys.time()
d2 <- distances(G, v=1, to=521)
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
# Time difference of 0.002238274 secs (consistently smaller than above)

start_time <- Sys.time()
D1 <- bounded_hop_pairG_1(G)
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
# Time difference of 2.671333 secs

start_time <- Sys.time()
D2 <- bounded_hop_pairG_2(G)
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
# Time difference of 1.101419 secs
```

Though I suspect my first function to apply early termination and never stores the full pairwise distance matrix, it appears to be much less efficient than my second function (which also performs a full unweighted pairwise distance computation) in terms of computational time. Hence, I was hoping somebody could point out the most efficient way to implement the first function in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try [cppRouting](https://github.com/vlarmet/cppRouting) package available via github. 
It provides functions like get_distance_matrix() which can use all cores.

```
library(cppRouting)
library(igraph)
library(spam)
library(Matrix)
# Sample graph
set.seed(42)
G <- sample_bipartite(500, 500, p=0.1)
E(G)$weight <- runif(length(E(G)))

#Graph to data frame 
G2<-as_long_data_frame(G)

#Weighted graph
graph1<-makegraph(G2[,1:3],directed = F)

#Unweighted graph
graph2<-makegraph(cbind(G2[,1:2],rep(1,nrow(G2))),directed = F)
nodes<-unique(c(G2$from,G2$to)) %>% sort

myfunc<-function(Gr1,Gr2,nd,k=2,cores=FALSE){
test<-get_distance_matrix(graph,nd,nd,allcores = cores)
test2<-get_distance_matrix(graph2,nd,nd,allcores = cores)
test[test2>k]<-0
return(as.spam(test))
}

#Your first function
system.time(
D1 <- bounded_hop_pairG_1(G)
)
#2.18s

#Your second function
system.time(
D2 <- bounded_hop_pairG_2(G)
)
#1.01s

#One core
system.time(
D3 <- myfunc(graph1,graph2,nodes))
#0.69s

#Parallel
system.time(
D4 <- myfunc(graph1,graph2,nodes,cores=TRUE))
#0.32s
```

If you really want to stop the algorithm when k-nodes is reached and have a little knowledge in C++, it seems rather simple to slightly modify original Dijkstra algorithm then use it via Rcpp.

Comment: I investigated what igraphs distances function is actually doing a bit more and I agree that just modifying it in C++ and calling it in R would be the way to go in general. Going to take some effort to get me going though :)